# Tuning SQL Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-tuning

I don't know too much about optimized SQL Selects and my query is very slow. Maybe you have some hints that makes my query faster.

SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLI.FANTASIA AS Cliente
            ,   DBSMP.VEICULO_PLACA AS Placa
            ,   DBSMP.DTINICIOPREV AS 'Data Inicio Previsto'
            ,   DBSMP.DTFIMPREV AS 'Data Fim Previsto'
            ,   DBSMP.DTINICIOREAL AS 'Data Incio Real'
            ,   DBSMP.DTFIMREAL AS 'Data Fim Real'
            ,   DBSMP.CIDADE_DES AS 'Cidade Destino'
            ,   DBSMP.CIDADE_ORI AS 'Cidade Origem'
            ,   TRA.FANTASIA AS Transportador
FROM DBSMP_WORK WORK
INNER JOIN DBSMP ON WORK.ID_SMP = DBSMP.ID_SMP
INNER JOIN DBCLIENTE CLI ON DBSMP.ID_CLIENTE = CLI.ID_CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN DBCLIENTE TRA ON DBSMP.ID_TRANSPORTADOR = CLI.ID_CLIENTE
WHERE WORK.[status] IN ('F')
    AND DBSMP.ID_CLIENTE IN (85, 107, 137, 139, 510, 658, 659, 661, 702)
    AND TRA.RAZAO = 'Google'
    AND DBSMP.DTINICIOPREV BETWEEN '01/01/1900' AND '02/09/2013'
```

Then, my question is: How can I make abovequery faster?

This query must to run in an instance of SQL Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the execution plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few thoughts:

- try not to use `DISTINCT`, instead restrict your data appropriate.
- try not to use `IN`, for example `IN('F')` can be `='F'`
- read about indices and create them for the columns which you are querying/joining
- read how to create and read execution plans to find the bottleneck

Comment: I'm getting duplicated data if i don't use DISTINCT, exists a good aproach to do this without DISTINCT?

Comment: @guisantogui identify why there are those duplicates. Most likely the come because of a JOIN. Then you should adapt your JOIN clause to not get these duplicates anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLI.FANTASIA AS Cliente
            ,   DBSMP.VEICULO_PLACA AS Placa
            ,   DBSMP.DTINICIOPREV AS [Data Inicio Previsto]
            ,   DBSMP.DTFIMPREV AS [Data Fim Previsto]
            ,   DBSMP.DTINICIOREAL AS [Data Incio Real]
            ,   DBSMP.DTFIMREAL AS [Data Fim Real]
            ,   DBSMP.CIDADE_DES AS [Cidade Destino]
            ,   DBSMP.CIDADE_ORI AS [Cidade Origem]
            ,   TRA.FANTASIA AS Transportador
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM DBSMP
    WHERE DBSMP.DTINICIOPREV BETWEEN '19000101' AND '20130902'
        AND DBSMP.ID_CLIENTE IN (85, 107, 137, 139, 510, 658, 659, 661, 702)
) DBSMP
JOIN DBCLIENTE CLI ON DBSMP.ID_CLIENTE = CLI.ID_CLIENTE
JOIN DBCLIENTE TRA ON DBSMP.ID_TRANSPORTADOR = TRA.ID_CLIENTE -- or TRA.ID_TRANSPORTADOR = CLI.ID_CLIENTE
WHERE TRA.RAZAO = 'Google'
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM DBSMP_WORK WORK
        WHERE WORK.ID_SMP = DBSMP.ID_SMP
            AND WORK.[status] = 'F'
    )
```

Comment: The `DBSMP.ID_TRANSPORTADOR = TRA.ID_CLIENTE` looks more plausible, based on the names.

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need the final `LEFT JOIN`.  You have the condition `TRA.RAZAO = 'Google'` in the `WHERE` clause.  This effective turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an inner join.

The most important thing, though, is the `join` condition:

```
LEFT JOIN DBCLIENTE TRA ON DBSMP.ID_TRANSPORTADOR = CLI.ID_CLIENTE
```

In other words, your query does not make sense.  You are joining in a table with no reference to the table.  I am not sure what the right fix is, because you don't give enough information.  My best guess is that this is what you mean for the `from` clause:

```
FROM DBSMP_WORK WORK 
INNER JOIN DBSMP ON WORK.ID_SMP = DBSMP.ID_SMP
INNER JOIN DBCLIENTE CLI ON DBSMP.ID_CLIENTE = CLI.ID_CLIENTE
LEFT JOIN DBCLIENTE TRA ON TRA.ID_TRANSPORTADOR = CLI.ID_CLIENTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indices on the columns `ID_SMP`,`ID_CLIENTE`,`ID_TRANSPORTATOR` in their various tables. This will make the joining operations much faster. And then, to finish it off you can try indexing the columns `STATUS`, `RAZAO` and `DTINICIOPREV` in the `WHERE`clause too.

Answer (score -1):

your M$ tooling should have a query analyzer/expain tool that shows you the joins and expressions and their "cost" - use this in an iterative process when improving your statement.

add indizes to columns that take part in a join clause or the where clause

try to remove all selected column and replace the with "1" (-> SELECT 1 FROM ..) - this will show you, if the data set is too big

try to remove the DISTINCT as it performs an expensive group by value